# AJAX response from server undefined - only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, tomcat7

### I'm sending an input text from a HTML page to a servlet on a Tomcat 7 server and I'm supposed to receive the same input as a response (which is enclosed in an XML tab in the servlet) but I'm getting undefined

I'm new to AJAX and Javascript and, so I'm following some video tutorials. I'm trying to follow an AJAX tutorial which performs an echo. It is a relatively simple example - not right now for me.

Here's ajaxtutorial.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>AJAX Tutorial</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        enter name: <input type="text" id="inputdisplay" size="25/">
        <button type="button" onclick="sendMessageToServer()">send to server:</button><br/>
        reply received from server:<input type="text" id="textdisplay" size="30"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var xmlHttpRequest;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
                xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("MICROSOFT.XMLHTTP");
            }else{
                alert("Your browser does not dupport XMLHTTP!")
            } 
            function sendMessageToServer(){
                xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "AjaxDemoServlet?name="+document.getElementById("inputdisplay").value,true);
                xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=receiveMessageFromServer;
                xmlHttpRequest.send();
                document.getElementById("inputdisplay").value="";
            }
            function receiveMessageFromServer(){
                //xmlHttpRequest.readyState==4 ==> The XMLHttpRequest has loaded - The data transfer has completed
                //xmlHttpRequest.status==200 ==> OK - The request was fulfilled
                if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState==4&&xmlHttpRequest.status==200){
                    alert(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
                    document.getElementById("textdisplay").value = xmlHttpRequest.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("responseFromServer")[0].text;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The alert displays "hi input" between open&closed responseFromServer xml tags but the "textdisplay" displays undefined**

Here's the servlet, AjaxDemoServlet.java

```
package com.tudor.AjaxTutorial;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/AjaxDemoServlet")
public class AjaxDemoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public AjaxDemoServlet() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {}
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("server received the following message from client: "+request.getParameter("name"));
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        response.getWriter().println("<responseFromServer>hi "+request.getParameter("name")+"</responseFromServer>");
        System.out.println("server replied with the following message to client: hi "+request.getParameter("name"));

    }

}
```

*It seems that only on Firefox i'm receiving the* **undefined** *answer. Both Internet Explorer and the Eclipse browser are displaying properly. Sorry for the narrowness*

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Look at the HTTP respond in your browsers developer tools. Does it have the content you expect? Does the XML pass validation? What happens when you `console.log()` `xmlHttpRequest.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("responseFromServer")[0]`? or `xmlHttpRequest.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("responseFromServer")`? or `xmlHttpRequest.responseXML`?

Comment: Use `jQuery.ajax`; with a `.done()`, `.error()` function and you'll be able to atleast find the issue.

Comment: @Killrawr — How will that help find the error? The `alert` is firing, so the request itself is successful.

Comment: @Quentin `AJAX response from server undefined`; jQuery `error` gives some detailed data regarding errors that occur during `ajax` event.

Comment: @Quentin
`xmlHttpRequest.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("responseFromServer")[0]` has the property `textContent="hi input"`
the console.log doesn't display anything

Comment: @Killrawr — Since the alert is firing, there aren't any errors that occurred during the ajax event!

Comment: @Tudormi — So you can see `textContent` but can't understand by `text` is `undefined`?

Comment: @Quentin indeed, i can see `textContent` containing the provided input but firefox displayed `undefined`. The answer given by Si Kelly solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  problem is with this line:

```
document.getElementById("textdisplay").value = xmlHttpRequest.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("responseFromServer")[0].text;
```

`getElementsByTagName()` returns an array of Nodes that don't have .text as a standard property. You need to call `.textContent` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

Comment: Indeed, calling `.textContent` will work for firefox but won't work for IE or Eclipse's built-in browser.
So, `.text' for the last 2 browsers and `.textContent` for firefox. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes looks like it's only supported in IE9+. I think Eclipse uses an IE component provided by Windows anyway.